# Scoring races + ranking index, with Bayesian approach

Tags: bayesian, estimation, ranking, rating

- Challenge: Is this the best approach for scoring multicompetitor races? How do I account for both uncertain prior & uncertain evidence when scoring?
- Case: athletes getting *scores* in each race, relative to their performance. Athletes also getting *ranking index* based on their X best scores within the ranking period. That is, two scoring processes.
- Idea: Using a Bayesian approach for both scoring processes, like this: `w ∗ R + (1 − w) ∗ C`

### Process 1 (scoring a race)

1. Estimate `estStandardPerformance` (the estimated performance that would give a score of 100%), based on known parameters (such as distance).
2. Calculate predicted performance for each athlete, based on their (weighted) index. `predPerformance = estStandardPerformance / Index`.
3. Compare the difference between actual performance and predicted performance for each athlete and take the average, `k = avg(actualPerformance / predPerformance)`.
4. The average difference = `k`, a correction factor that is applied to `estStandardPerformance` to get a more correct `StandardPerformance` (by taking into account all unknown factors that affect the performances on race day). `StandardPerformance = estStandardPerformance * k`
5. Calculate estimated score for each athlete: `estScore = standardPerformance / racePerformance`
6. `Score = w * estScore + (1 - w) * avgEstScores` (where `avgEstScores` is the mean of all athletes' `estScore` and `w = v / (v + m)`, with v being the total number of athletes in the race and m a constant, that I would probably set to around 0.5-1).

#6 is the Bayesian-style equation that basically gives lower scores the fewer the athletes. BUT, since predicted performance in #2 is based on each athlete's Index (which is not a point estimate, but a Probability Density Function, PDF), **how do I take both uncertainties into account when scoring**? That is, there are degrees of uncertainty both for `predictedPerformance` (depending on each runner's Index PDF) as well as for `Score` (with more athletes = higher certainty).

### Process 2 (index based on scores)

Using the same formula as in #4 above, we can calculate Index for an athlete from their best X scores in the ranking period.

`Index = w * meanScore + (1 - w) * meanAll` (where `meanScore` is the mean of the athlete's best X scores, and `meanAll` is the mean of ALL athletes' Index. `w` is again `v / (v / M)`, where `v` now is the number of races the athlete has (up to a maximum of X) and `m` is another constant, in this case around 0.05.

And then Index should not be a Point Estimate, but a Probability Density Function (higher uncertainty with fewer ranked races). **How can I calculate this uncertainty, in order to take that into account in future race scoring processes**?

### Summary

I think this approach would work pretty well, by giving lower scores and index when certainty is less. My main challenge is **how to account for the double uncertainty factors in the first process of scoring a race and particularly the Index uncertainty**.

Input welcome!